# Limit of $S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{i^k}{n^{k+1}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{i^k}{n^{k+1}} $ . For what values of $k$ the series $S_n$ is convergent and what is the value of convergence ? I'm really unable to understand $S_n$ because I haven't seen any series which is similar to that , so applying tests isn't possible for me . Also I've searched over the internet but didn't find any useful result .

Comment: @gimusi When $-1 \lt k \le 0$ , $S_n$ converges or diverges ?

Comment: my hint was given for the case $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ since I thought for this limitation, you can refer to the other answer for the general case (as for example by the integral test).

Comment: Possibly the OP has a different problem in mind than what was treated in the proposed duplicate.  Note the wording "For what values of $k$ the series $S_n$ is convergent?"  Since $S_n$ is itself a finite series, it trivially converges.  Perhaps the issue is whether the *sequence* $\{S_n\}$ converges, as $n\to \infty$, the topic addressed by the proposed duplicate (at least for some exponents $m$).  The Comment left by the OP above asks about exponents in the range $-1\lt k \le 0$, where $k$ in this Question plays the role of $m$ in the proposed duplicate.  Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

- If $k>0$,
  $$S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^k\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow} \int_0^1 x^kdx.$$

I let you see the case where $k\leq 0$.

- If $k=0$ it's obvious (since $(S_n)$ is constant).
- If $k<0$ you can easily show that $(S_n)$ diverge.

Comment: So by using improper integrals $S_n$ converges when $k \gt -1$ and convergence value is $\frac{1}{k+1}$ ?

Comment: @Surb nice, awarded point.

Comment: @S.H.W Note that Surb specified a formula **if k>0**

Comment: @user2661923 What we can do if $k \le 0$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W : I'm sure you can answer this question look that $S_n$ is something like $n^{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^k}$.

Comment: @Surb My teacher told me that it converges when $-1 \lt k \le 0 $ . Is it wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Since $x^k$ monotonically increases, we have

$$\frac{n^{k+1}-1}{k+1}=\int_1^{n} x^k\,dx\le \sum_{k=1}^n i^k\le \int_1^{n+1}x^k\,dx=\frac{(n+1)^{k+1}}{k+1}\tag 1$$

whence dividing by $n^{k+1}$, letting $n\to\infty$, and applying the squeeze theorem to $(1)$, we find that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i^k}{n^{k+1}}=\frac1{k+1}$$

Comment: Can you explain the inequality ?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that  $\sum_{i = 1}^n {i^k}$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k+1$.

[Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

Comment: Thanks but why that is true ?

Comment: @S.H.W It is a general result which can be proved by induction or by Faulhaber's formula (I've just added the link).

Answer (score 0):

If you enjoy generalized harmonic numbers, you can find the limit and approximate the partial sums since
$$S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{i^k}{n^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{n^{k+1}}\sum_{i = 1}^n i^k=\frac{H_n^{(-k)}}{n^{k+1}}$$ Now, using asymptotics
$$H_n^{(-k)}=n^k \left(\frac{n}{k+1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{k}{12
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)+\zeta (-k)$$ and get
$$S_n=\left(\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{k}{12
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)+\frac {\zeta (-k)}{n^{k+1}}$$ For illustration purposes, using $k=\pi$, here are a few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 1.0106954353 & 1.0000000000 \\
 2 & 0.5573245570 & 0.5566573661 \\
 3 & 0.4372871463 & 0.4371554062 \\
 4 & 0.3828393613 & 0.3827976837 \\
 5 & 0.3519344645 & 0.3519173945 \\
 6 & 0.3320630018 & 0.3320547700 \\
 7 & 0.3182267765 & 0.3182223333 \\
 8 & 0.3080449761 & 0.3080423716 \\
 9 & 0.3002414849 & 0.3002398589 \\
 10 & 0.2940715381 & 0.2940704713 \\
 11 & 0.2890715458 & 0.2890708172 \\
 12 & 0.2849379775 & 0.2849374630 \\
 13 & 0.2814638355 & 0.2814634620 \\
 14 & 0.2785031372 & 0.2785028595 \\
 15 & 0.2759499934 & 0.2759497827 \\
 16 & 0.2737257376 & 0.2737255748 \\
 17 & 0.2717707116 & 0.2717705839 \\
 18 & 0.2700388547 & 0.2700387531 \\
 19 & 0.2684940402 & 0.2684939583 \\
 20 & 0.2671075359 & 0.2671074692
\end{array}
\right)$$